# Seasonality tests

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autocorrelation, seasonality

I have data which I need to check for seasonality. Now I found two methods to do this, the autocorrelation plot and the rank Von Neumann ratio.
Now I found the autocorrelation has some requirements:

- Data should be normally distributed or be reasonably symmetrical
- There has to be 8 to 10 available data points
- The data shouldn't contain outliers

Since my data is all between 0 and 4 and discrete, my data isn't normally distributed (it's Poisson) so I'm not able to use the autocorrelation. However, I found the following requirement for the rank Von Neumann ratio.

- Check that the data are not autocorrelated.

What do they mean I should do if I can't check autocorrelation because I have no normal distribution?

Are there other tests available which I could use with my data? I have 26 monthly data points, Poisson distributed.

**Edit:**

To clear it up. I have data of the last 26 months. This data differs between 40 and 160. This data is divided in 4 categories, with in each category between 6 and 50 groups, with a total of 100+ groups. I need to do forecasts on group-level. I found graphically that there may be seasonal influences on the pooled data, but since the group-level data is mostly 0 and 1, there probably isn't any seasonality (or trend). To support this assumption I want(ed) to do formal tests to test the seasonality and trend.

Example graphs

[image]

[image]

**Added graphs:**

The total averages and the total averages of category 1 and 2

[image]

Cumulatives of everything and of categories

[image]

Comment: Plotting the data against time and against time of year (in this case month) is the best single way to check for seasonality. I know this doesn't qualify as a formal test which some seem to think indispensable, but with time series, seasonality is often obvious and if it's not evident on a graph it may be absent or trivial. In this case autocorrelation is at best an ambiguous test as it will be thrown off by any trend, which although not mentioned here is another thing to check for.

Comment: 26 time points are probably too few for very much formal time series analysis in any case. You don't give a checkable source for the advice about the von Neumann ratio.

Comment: @NickCox Here's a source: `http://www.itrcweb.org/gsmc-1/Content/GW%20Stats/5%20Methods%20in%20indiv%20Topics/5%208%20Temporal%20Analysis.htm`. Aren't there any formal tests for this topic? Since it's for my thesis they'd want to see something based on literature. Graphs don't say too much I guess, because the value is 0 most of the time, and sometimes 1, rarely more. The times it's 1 it's hard to see if it's random or because of seasonality.

Comment: You make my point for me, unfortunately: if the seasonality isn't evident then unfortunately either it's elusive or your sample is too small to do much (unwelcome advice, no doubt, if the data were hard won and there are no more to get). For most months you necessarily have just two values. I'd perhaps look at something like a Markov chain. Most time series analysis isn't focused on data like yours.

Comment: I can't speak for your system, but I've supervised and examined many Ph.D. students and evidence of looking hard at the data and thinking about them is exactly what I encourage and reward, never doing a test for its own sake. Otherwise, good method choice doesn't depend on whether it is for a thesis, at any level.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36409/discussion-on-question-by-grafit-seasonality-tests).